# On submit of model form want to post value in a php variable

Tags: php, jquery

Thank all for you great help for my previous question.

now again i am stuck in problem.

**Question :** i am using model form to submit password. on submit of model form i want to call action as $_POST or $_REQUEST. but i am not able to get post action in php code. below is my code

File Name:  password.php

```
          <?php
            // i try both method
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            {
            var_dump($_REQUEST['data']); die;
            }

            /*if($_REQUEST['data'])
            {
                $password=$_REQUEST['data'];   

                var_dump($password);
             die;
            }*/
            ?>
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Reset Password</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <style>
            body { font-size: 62.5%; }
            label, input { display:block; }
            input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
            fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
            h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
            div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
            div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
            div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
            .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
            .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.001em; }
            .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display:none !important;}
            </style>
            <script>
            $(function() 
            {
                var password = $( "#password" ), RePassword = $( "#RePassword" ), allFields = $( [] ).add(password).add(RePassword ),tips = $( ".validateTips" );
                function updateTips( t ) 
                {
                    tips.text( t ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                    setTimeout(function() 
                    {
                        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
                    }, 500 );
                }
                function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) 
                {
                    var pass=password.val();
                    var repass=RePassword.val();
                    if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) 
                    {
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + "." );
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(pass != repass)
                    {
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        updateTips( "password not match." );
                        return false;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) 
                {
                    if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) 
                    {
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        updateTips( n );
                        return false;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog(
                {
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    height: 250,
                    width: 300,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "submit": function(e) {
                            var bValid = true;
                            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 8, 16 );
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( RePassword, "RePassword", 8, 16 );

                            if ( bValid ) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url : 'adq.php',
                                    data: {password: RePassword.val()},                                     
                                    success: function(e)
                                    {
                                        console.log("successfull");
                                    }
                                });         
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    close: function() 
                    {
                        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new password">
                    <p class="validateTips"></p>
                    <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                            <label for="RePassword">Re-Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="RePassword" id="RePassword" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

for more details kindly comment.

Comment: What do you mean unable to get it?  From the looks of the commented section, you are looking in the wrong place as you check for `$_REQUEST['data']` where you submit would be accessed as `$_POST['password']` or `$_REQUEST['password']`.  The `data` portion of the ajax is what will be posted as variables, which you declare to be `password`

Comment: try with if(isset($_POST['password'])) die($_POST['password']);

Comment: hi john i try with password also but its not happening. thank for reply

Comment: i try with this also but its not working  `if(isset($_REQUEST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password'];      var_dump($password); die; }`

Comment: kawashita86 i try this but same its not working. i saw in inspect element its returning html `password which i enter ` in response it showing pre code with entered password

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the response received to the web page when using ajax. The form is submitted but you don't see changes in the web page because you actually didn't specify what should be done with the data. You may use `$(#elementID).html(html_)` to set an element's inner HTML to the data received assuming that `elementID` is the element ID where you want to put your data and `html_` is the data received from ajax.

**Example**

The following should work assuming that a file of name **adq.php** exists, the element of ID `dialog-form` is the element which you want to change its inner HTML to the one received from ajax and the data you want to submit is `RePassword.val()`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : 'adq.php',
    data: {password: RePassword.val()},                                     
    success: function(e)
    {
       $("#dialog-form").html(e); 
       // console.log("successfull");
    }
});
```

**Full contents of the PHP file**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    var_dump($_REQUEST['password']);
}

/*if($_REQUEST['data'])
{
    $password=$_REQUEST['data'];   

    var_dump($password);
 die;
}*/
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Reset Password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
body { font-size: 62.5%; }
label, input { display:block; }
input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
.validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.001em; }
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display:none !important;}
</style>
<script>
$(function() 
{
    var password = $( "#password" ), RePassword = $( "#RePassword" ), allFields = $( [] ).add(password).add(RePassword ),tips = $( ".validateTips" );
    function updateTips( t ) 
    {
        tips.text( t ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
        }, 500 );
    }
    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) 
    {
        var pass=password.val();
        var repass=RePassword.val();
        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) 
        {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + "." );
            return false;
        }
        else if(pass != repass)
        {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "password not match." );
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) 
    {
        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) 
        {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog(
    {
        closeOnEscape: false,
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 250,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "submit": function(e) {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 8, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( RePassword, "RePassword", 8, 16 );

                if ( bValid ) {

                e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : 'adq.php',
                        data: {password: RePassword.val()},                                     
                        success: function(e)
                        {
                           $("#dialog-form").html(e); 
                           // console.log("successfull");
                        }
                    });         
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
        },
        close: function() 
        {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new password">
        <p class="validateTips"></p>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <label for="RePassword">Re-Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="RePassword" id="RePassword" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notice** You should also use `$_REQUEST['password']` in PHP to get the value submitted instead of `$_REQUEST['data']` as the name of the field indicated in the HTML was `password` and not `data` as [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866861/on-submit-of-model-form-want-to-post-value-in-a-php-variable/20867174#comment31308267_20866861) stated.

Comment: hey jon its also not working i try with it. for more info i did inspect element there in response body it showing    `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'123455678'</font> <i>(length=8)</i> </pre>`

Comment: @radhikakumari I'm really sorry looks like I didn't notice your jQuery code, I've edited the answer to fit your needs. Happy new year!